# why audio visualizing a livestream is not working on mobile / Safari?

Tags: javascript, three.js, safari, web-audio-api

I'm trying to make an audio livestream visualizer based on the three.js example:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=visua#webaudio_visualizer

It does not work on Safari or iPhone mobiles (Safari, Chrome).
Using an mp3 file instead of a livestream works in all devices.

```
    var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
    var audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );
    // not working on iPhone (Chrome, or Safari) or Safari Desktop
    var mediaElement = new Audio( 'https://c2.radioboss.fm:18071/stream' );

    //this works ok everywhere:
    //var mediaElement = new Audio( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.mp3' );

    mediaElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    mediaElement.loop = true;
    mediaElement.play();
    audio.setMediaElementSource( mediaElement );
    analyser = new THREE.AudioAnalyser( audio, fftSize );
```

https://codepen.io/pesinasiller/pen/Pvevry 
(lines 23-24)

There is no error message, but the audio data from the analizer is always 0 on mobile.

Comment: Can you actually hear the audio stream on iOS devices?

Comment: yes, you can @Mugen87

Comment: analyzing live streaming in Safari broke sometime in fall 2018 in both desktop and iOS: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195043