# How to make Safari execute THREE.AudioLoader() properly?

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js, safari, mobile-safari

Lately I am working on a piece of code that makes the browser play an audio, using Three.js. Below lies the related snippet:

```js
function loadAudio(i) {
    document.getElementById('overlay').innerHTML =
        '<div class="text-loading">a moment please...</div>'
    const files = [
        'https://xxx.yyy.com/1.mp3',
        'https://xxx.yyy.com/2.mp3',
        'https://xxx.yyy.com/3.mp3',
        'https://xxx.yyy.com/4.mp3',
    ]
    const file = files[i]

    const loader = new THREE.AudioLoader()
    loader.load(file, function (buffer) {
        audio.setBuffer(buffer)
        audio.play()
        analyser = new THREE.AudioAnalyser(audio, fftSize)
        init()
    })
}
```

However, I am notified that the website did not quite work on Desktop and Mobile Safari (where I initially tested upon but I released the code whatsoever when it worked on Chrome on my MacBook, thought it was internet problem..), and I still couldn't figure out what do to after perusing all related questions on stackoverflow (forgive me for my stupidity).

Can someone please help me with it?

---

also, some related links might be handy:

- [why audio visualizing a livestream is not working on mobile / Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317686/why-audio-visualizing-a-livestream-is-not-working-on-mobile-safari)
- https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-audioloader-not-playing-other-audio-format-except-wav-on-iphone-safari-browser/23844/3
- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10404
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195043 (might this be something related to webkit?)

Comment: Can you please verify if the following example does work on your devices? https://threejs.org/examples/webaudio_visualizer

Comment: @Mugen87 hmm.. is there supposed to be music? there indeed are some yellow pixels jumping to and fro on my iPhone but there is no sound.

Comment: @Mugen87 Ah a play button popped up on my MacBook when I visit the site and it work.. well then guess the only way possible is adding a play button?... apple is weird...

Comment: You need a user interaction before starting an audio feed. That is defined by an autoplay policy which is in place by most major browsers. So do it like in the example and start to create you audio objects right after the user has interacted with your app (e.g. clicked a start button).